# Summarize multiple values with jq reduce

Tags: json, jq, reduce

How to use jq's `reduce` function to handle multiple manipulations?

Given a model like:

```
{
  "usage" : {
    "os:linux" : {
      "2018_11_18" : {
        "amount" : 601046342,
        "credits" : 99783
      },
      "2018_10_18" : {
        "amount" : 839785106,
        "credits" : 173121
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And JQ file:

```
reduce .usage."os:linux"[] as $item (
{"credits":0,"minutes":0}; 
."credits" += $item.credits
)
```

I Get:

```
{
  "credits": 272904,
  "minutes": 0
}
```

Cool, But I want to toal both fields, something like:

```
reduce .usage."os:linux"[] as $item (
{"credits":0,"minutes":0}; 
."credits" += $item.credits,
."minutes" += $item.amount /1000/60
)
```

Semi-colons cause errors, commas pass, but just handles the last task, i,e,

```
{
  "credits": 0,
  "minutes": 24013.85746666667
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always the explicit way:

```
reduce .usage."os:linux"[] as $item (
  {"credits": 0, "minutes": 0 }; 
  {
    "credits": (.credits + $item.credits),
    "minutes": (.minutes + $item.amount / 60000) 
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or more succintly:

```
reduce .usage."os:linux"[] as $item (
  {}; 
  .credits += $item.credits
  | .minutes += ($item.amount / 60000) )
```

### Or ...

Or abstracting the reduction into the general-purpose utility function `sigma/1`:

```
def sigma(s): reduce s as $s (null; . + $s);

.usage."os:linux"
| {credits: sigma(.[].credits),
   minutes: (sigma(.[].amount) / 60000) }
```